# Generic type for key in array.reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

Have a array of object and by reduce I transform it to {key: [{}], [{}]}, key is date of array
like: [{date: '22-02-06-00:55:66', name: 'one'}...] and result will be {22-02-06: [{}]} all items what includes to this date. My function is:

```
export function getObjectOfArrayByKey<T, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T[],
  key: K,
  timeFormat: string,
  dateFormat: string,
): { [key in keyof T]: T[] } {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const time = dayjs(item[key]).format(timeFormat);
    const date = dayjs(item[key]).format(dateFormat);

    const equalToDate = {
      time,
      ...item,
    };

    acc[date] = acc[date] || [];

    acc[date].push(equalToDate);

    return acc;
  }, {} as { [key in keyof T]: T[] & { time: string } });
}
```

But in constant equalToDate I add new value "time" and I don’t know how add to type script this new type for time.

I think problem is here, I need add new property for type of new array

```
{ [key in keyof T]: T[] & { time: string }
```

Answer (score 0):

property time to the objects in the array returned by the getObjectOfArrayByKey function

```
export interface ObjectWithTime<T> extends T {
  time: string;
}

export function getObjectOfArrayByKey<T, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T[],
  key: K,
  timeFormat: string,
  dateFormat: string,
): { [key in keyof T]: ObjectWithTime<T>[] } {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const time = dayjs(item[key]).format(timeFormat);
    const date = dayjs(item[key]).format(dateFormat);

    const equalToDate: ObjectWithTime<T> = {
      time,
      ...item,
    };

    acc[date] = acc[date] || [];

    acc[date].push(equalToDate);

    return acc;
  }, {} as { [key in keyof T]: ObjectWithTime<T>[] });
}
```

Comment: thanks, I did it but then get error for other properties in array: 
Property 'faviconBase64' does not exist on type 'ObjectWithNewKey<{ id: string; title: string; url: string; visitedAt: string; faviconBase64: string; incognito: boolean; }>'